# Getting error while deploying function to firestore/firebase to fetch data from firestore database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data from the collection name pixster but getting an error. There is a collection in firestore with name pixster that contain data. I want to fetch that data but getting an error.

```
Here is my code

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports.alifunction = functions.firestore
.document(){
var serviceAccount = require('/Users/pc/Functions/functions/ali1-dac45-bba93b475d3a.json');

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
db.collection('pixster').get()
.then((snapshot) => {
  if (!doc || !doc.exists) {
  throw new Error("data does not exists");
           }
  return snapshot.map((doc) => {
  return  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
return  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: by commenting .document() then the function is getting deployed but not getting out put in console..

Comment: If we don't comment .document() then get syntax error

Comment: That's because you have a syntax error on that line.

Comment: Is everything other than this is okay @Michael.Lumley